Issue with Overriding Subscription Function Code in AppSync Resolver Pipeline
I’m currently working on an AWS AppSync project and I’m facing an issue with overriding the default subscription function in my resolver pipeline. Here is a detailed explanation of the problem:
Context:
I have a default AppSync subscription on my model Score. I need to customize the resolver logic for this subscription using VTL files.
What I’ve Done:

Created the required VTL files in the resolvers directory:

Subscription.onCreateScore.req.vtl

Subscription.onCreateScore.res.vtl



Pushed using amplify push

I can see the resolver in my build directory by my resolver pipeline still shows old code.
I tried to push it as preAuth.1.res which shows the function in pipeline but it gives me following error:
"message": "Connection failed: {"errors":[{"errorType":"MappingTemplate","message":"Unsupported element '$[operation]'."}]}"
If I add this function as by going to aws console -> amplify -> functions same code works.
here are the VTL Files.
VTL Content:
Subscription.onCreateScore.req.vtl:
vtl

{ "version": "2017-02-28", "operation": "Invoke", "payload": { "identity": $context.identity, "arguments": $context.arguments } }

Subscription.onCreateScore.res.vtl:
vtl
vtl

#set($gameIds = $ctx.result) #if($gameIds && $ctx.prev.result.items) 
#set($filteredItems = []) #foreach($item in $ctx.prev.result.items) 
#if($gameIds[$item.gameId]) $util.qr($filteredItems.add($item)) #end #end { "items": $filteredItems } #else $util.toJson($gameIds) #end

Request for Help:

What might be causing this error?

Is there a better way to set up or override the subscription resolver with custom VTL templates in AppSync?

Are there specific steps I should follow to ensure the VTL files are correctly picked up and deployed?


Thank you in advance for your help!
